# split <b>'s in php

Tags: php, arrays, split

For this code i need to take a string like

```
<b>hey</b> more text<b>hey2</b> other text
```

and i expect the returned array to look like

```
<b>hey</b> more text
<b>hey2</b> other text
```

However it doesnt. How do i make it look like the above? my test code is

```
$myArr = split("<b>", "<b>hey</b> more text<b>hey2</b> other text");
foreach($myArr as $e)
{
    echo "e = $e\n-------------\n";
}
```

output is

```
e =
-------------
e = hey</b> more text
-------------
e = hey2</b> other text
```

I need the b>'s to remain. How should i remove the first empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "split" function has been deprecated, it is better not to use it.

Instead, use "explode" on <b> and then prepend back onto each element, and pop the first element off the array.

Comment: how do i pop the first element? i only seen poping of the last

Comment: Pop is a function that removes the first element off a 'stack' type data structure. Dequeue is a function that removes the last element out of a 'queue' type data structure. PHP arrays can be used as either depending on the functions you apply against it.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "e = <b>$e\n-------------\n";
```

You need to prepend the <b> because split removes it from the string.

As for the empty elements of the array try:

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use it as you have it and add a $e = "".$e; before the echo

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `<b>` after splitting, and just `pop()` the first variable in the array.

Comment: The pop wouldn't work in case of broken html: <b><b>asd<b><b><b>asd ;)

Comment: Well, you could always do a check `if ($array[0] == "") //popThatShit()`

Comment: Well yes, but if you try it you would see that you would get more empty values than just [0] :)

Comment: foreach ($val in $array) if ($val == "") poppinThangs(); Anything else? :p